# Can you share custom maps in Age of Empires 1, and how?

Tags: pc, age-of-empires

I made a custom map and want to play it with my family. This is a 4 person map and they don't have it, can I send it to them or even sneaker-net it to their computers?

Comment: Check where the map is saved on your computer. If you can do it easily then it's most likely possible to just copy the file and have your family paste it in the same folder on their computer